# No permission, access forbidden - codeigniter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a small problem with a login tutorial with CodeIgniter after calling a certain function in the main controller this error is given:

Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

I am using XAMPP for the mac and not sure whats going wrong.. although the htaccess CodeIgniter has supplied me with has this "Deny from all"

How do I change permissions on my localhost via xampp? does it all need to be 777? or is my htaccess wrong?

Answer (score 4):

It was the baseurl, never add /application/ because I learned the hard way that everything in application is protected because of the htaccess so people can't access core files! THANKS CODEIGNITER for being so safe :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't have that error anymore, I just had it and I fixed it with the permission.

```
root: ls -lrht
....
-rwxr-xr-x@   1 root     admin   199B Mar  1 13:34 .htaccess
...
root: chown jcho360 .htaccess 
root: ls -lrth
t...
-rwxr-xr-x@   1 jcho360  admin   199B Mar  1 13:34 .htaccess
...
root:
```

after this, it worked PERFECT